# Rotate X-Axis Labels for d3 area_series chart in Rubix - ReactJs Powered Admin Template

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, charts

I am using Rubix - ReactJs Powered Admin Template for the project development. Also, I am using d3.js to render various charts. As the labels on x-axis are horizontally aligned they are merging into each other.

Here is my code snippet to create a area_series chart:

```
var chart = new Rubix('#slcnm', {
width: '100%',
height: 200,
title: 'Data Load Frequency',
subtitle: 'no markers',
titleColor: '#0054A9',
subtitleColor: '#0054A9',
axis: {
    x: {
        type: 'datetime',
        tickFormat: '%d-%b-%Y'
       }
    },
    tooltip: {
    color: '#0054A9',
    format: {
        x: '.0f',
        y: '.0f'
      }
  }
});
var area = chart.area_series({
name: 'Marketing Automation',
color: '#804000',
marker: 'circle'
});
```

Which property should I use to rotate the labels on x-axis are they will be more presentable when the chart is rendered.